# asp.net razor colon operator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I was reading about asp.net mvc 3 and saw this piece razor view code

```
<div id="footer">
    @RenderSection("footer", required:false)
    @if(IsSectionDefined("Copyright"))
    {
        @RenderSection("copyright")
    }
        else
    {
        <hr /><span>Rights reserved for a better use.</span>
    }
    @this.RenderSection("Privacy", @<u>Privacy policy</u>)
</div>
```

What is that colon in "required:false" ? Is that a new C# operator ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [named parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx). Optional and named parameters were introduced in C# 4.0. Nothing to do with ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC or Razor.

Answer (score 2):

Feature is called [named argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)